# How do I test an Azure Internal Endpoint from a local dev client? (Test in Production)

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-virtual-network

**The big question:**

How do I get the **IP:port** of an internal endpoint from a local dev client *not* running inside the RoleEnvironment? Even if I could connect to my Azure network, my **test class in VS** (where I am trying to execute tests calls to the service directly) cannot make use of **RoleEnvironment.Roles["MyRole"].Instances;**, because it in and of itself, is not running in an Azure Role.

**The setup:**

- I have backend web services (Web API) as internal endpoints in my
  deployment/role. My front end website uses these services.
- I have a dev employee that needs to run tests against the internal endpoints using VS (unit tests)
- I do not have an on-premise network (small company, everyone works from home, no Active Directory per se, no domain server handling Windows auth, but we do have o365 accounts).

**The Requirements:**

1. I need the *local client* (not running inside the RoleEnvironment) to

   - Connect to Azure (VPN?)
   - Get the location (IP:Port) of the endpoint
2. The developer accessing the Azure network should have access only to these services, not to the entire box within Azure (i.e. not as admin in remote desktop, nor admin of the Azure portal, etc)

My situation is straight forward, and I would hope is common practice, but I can't find anyone on the interwebs that has addressed this.

**The Solution?**

[update] I have VPN working (Point to Site) and the cloud service deployed there. In order to hit the internal endpoints one must open up the firewall using s startup task. Done.   I also recently discovered ACLs for endpoints... but am not sure yet if or how that applies to my situation (my goal being to restrict access to developers with a role, etc)

Either way, HOW in the world do I get a reference to the endpoint? Sure, I can use RoleEnvironment.Roles from an app running in the environment (my front end website), but the VS client (local dev machine) is not running in said enviro.  I *can* manually look up the IP in the Virtual Network dashboard and manually look up the IP and port the specific service I want is running under.  But surely there is a programmatic, proper way...